# Why not "became" in "There is gradual improvement from the early 1990s until 2010, and then things become worse."

Tags: past-tense

In the sentence:

> There is gradual improvement from the early 1990s until 2010, and then things become
> worse.

As worsen things happened in the past, so why not **became** instead of **become**?

Comment: Are you also unsure about "is" rather than "was"?

Comment: @gotube No, I stll don't know. I think it is not right and difficult to understand. If it is right, when should we use past tense?

Answer (score 1):

As you appear to understand, "become" is present tense and "became" is past.

If the sentence was written in 2010 or shortly thereafter, there is no mystery: 2010 is the "present" and so something that happens in 2010 is properly given in present tense.

But that's probably not what's going on here. In English, we occasionally use an "historical present". That is, the author puts himself in some past time for narrative purposes and then writes as if that was the present. This is useful if he wants to refer to events past and present from that time, as it helps keeps the times straight. That is, suppose you want to talk about events that happened in 2000, 2010, and 2015. You are writing in 2023. You could refer to them all in the past tense. But this could get confusing. But if you use an historical present and set yourself in 2010, then 2010 is the present tense, 2000 is the past, and 2015 is the future.

This isn't used often in English, but I'm guessing that's what the writer is doing here. He writes as if 2010 is the present, so in 2010, it "becomes".

Comment: So, **become** and **became** are all correct? Which one is better?

Comment: _There was an improvement... then things became worse_ would be the normal way to say it. Here, the writer has chosen to put _both_ verbs in the present tense.

Comment: @KateBunting  Present and past tense, which is better ?

Comment: As I said, past tense is _normal_ in this context.  Jay has explained why the 'historical present' is _occasionally_ used.

Comment: @Y.zeng Personally, I would have put it all in past tense. I'd say that's "better" in this case. But one could debate such creative choices endlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Jay's explanation of "historical present" is spot on. It is established by "There is gradual improvement". Since the discussion is in the historical present, it should remain so, and present tense, "becomes", is approriate.

An alternate use would be simple past: "There was gradual improvement ... and then things became worse."

Unless you have good reason, don't switch tenses in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: How about this one: There **was** gradual improvement from the early 1990s until 2010, and then things **become** worse.

Comment: This can be used, but in a particular way. You might say this if  the next part of the discussion focusses heavily on just how bad things become. Here, the change in verb tense draws attention to the issue becoming worse.

Comment: You said that "Unless you have good reason, don't switch tenses in the middle of a sentence." What did you refer to by **middle of a sentence**?

Comment: @Y.zeng - In the example sentence, there are two parts, marked by the comma. Technically, these are independent clauses. Each clause could (with a little adjustment for the second one) form a standalone sentece. So "the middle of the sentence" refers to the junction of the two clauses.

Comment: May you tell me what is the **middle of a sentence** in my question sentence?

Comment: @Y.zeng - ", and", On either side you have an independent clause.